# How to get all params exept '.$0' and '._' using yargs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, yargs

When I am using yargs module to simplify params handling

Yargs always reruns params as an object, here is an example, if I run this command `node index.js default --optipn1=true --option2=false --custom`

Yargs return this array:

```
{
  _: [ 'default' ],
  optipn1: 'true',
  option2: 'false',
  custom: true,
  '$0': 'index.js'
}
```

What I want is the same array of params excluding `_` and `$0`,

```
{
  optipn1: 'true',
  option2: 'false',
  custom: true,
}
```

is there anyway to do that that?

Is there any built-in functionality to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
let obj = {
  _: ['default'],
  optipn1: 'true',
  option2: 'false',
  custom: true,
  '$0': 'index.js'
};
let {_, $0, ...targetObj} = obj;
console.log(targetObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  _: [ 'default' ],
  optipn1: 'true',
  option2: 'false',
  custom: true,
  '$0': 'index.js'
};


let newObj = {};


for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  if(key != '_' && key != '$0') {
    newObj = {...newObj, [`${key}`]: value}
  }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Here we go ;)
I hope be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```js
const configuration = yargs.argv;
delete configuration._;
delete configuration.$0;

console.log(configuration);
```

Typescript

```
import yargs from 'yargs';

const configuration: Record<string, unknown> = yargs.parseSync();
delete configuration._;
delete configuration.$0;
```